# Convolution matrix algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, convolution

Could someone help me understand how the convolution matrix works to get effects on images?I know that the value of a pixel(with each channel, for red, green and blue) is obtained as a sum of the original data matrix multiplied with the convolution matrix, but I do not get the algorithm.I hava a example taken from a website that makes a blur efect on an image.Could you help me with some explaining on the steps made?

```
Filters.tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
Filters.tmpCtx = Filters.tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');

Filters.createImageData = function(w,h) {
  return this.tmpCtx.createImageData(w,h);
};

Filters.convolute = function(pixels, weights, opaque) {
  var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(weights.length));
  var halfSide = Math.floor(side/2);
  var src = pixels.data;
  var sw = pixels.width;
  var sh = pixels.height;
  // pad output by the convolution matrix
  var w = sw;
  var h = sh;
  var output = Filters.createImageData(w, h);
  var dst = output.data;
  // go through the destination image pixels
  var alphaFac = opaque ? 1 : 0;
  for (var y=0; y<h; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x<w; x++) {
      var sy = y;
      var sx = x;
      var dstOff = (y*w+x)*4;
      // calculate the weighed sum of the source image pixels that
      // fall under the convolution matrix
      var r=0, g=0, b=0, a=0;
      for (var cy=0; cy<side; cy++) {
        for (var cx=0; cx<side; cx++) {
          var scy = sy + cy - halfSide;
          var scx = sx + cx - halfSide;
          if (scy >= 0 && scy < sh && scx >= 0 && scx < sw) {
            var srcOff = (scy*sw+scx)*4;
            var wt = weights[cy*side+cx];
            r += src[srcOff] * wt;
            g += src[srcOff+1] * wt;
            b += src[srcOff+2] * wt;
            a += src[srcOff+3] * wt;
          }
        }
      }
      dst[dstOff] = r;
      dst[dstOff+1] = g;
      dst[dstOff+2] = b;
      dst[dstOff+3] = a + alphaFac*(255-a);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
```

Comment: That is badly written code.

Comment: It is not mine, I am just trying to understand it, if you could help.

Comment: I realize that you didn't write it. I'm saying that it's bad code. Don't waste your time trying to understand a bad example.

Comment: Actually, I need it for a project, and I need to understand the algorithm  in order to use the convolution matrix in my project.Thank you for your advice, though.